# Where Do I find a Changelog for NEST?

Tags: elasticsearch, nuget, nest

We use (and like) NEST to access elasticsearch from C#. As noted on the nuget oage for NEST (http://nuget.org/packages/NEST), there are frequent releases. I tried to find some form of Changelog but could only find the git commits.

I searched the docs (http://nest.azurewebsites.net/), the source repo (https://github.com/Mpdreamz/NEST) and the nuget site but didn't find it.

Does some kind of Changelog exist and where can I find it?

Comment: now: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/releases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try my best to write proper release notes and put them on github issues as announcements:

https://github.com/Mpdreamz/NEST/issues

I also usually tweet about a new release with a link to the ticket describing whats new in the release.

Thanks for making me aware this might not be the most visible way to communicate new releases!.